# How can I use javascript to make a html <select> element with a pre selected value?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I'm trying to make a html  element with a preselected value but it seems to be random if the value I want to be preselected is the one selected or not

```
// elementName is a string and trueOrFalse is a boolean
let n = document.createElement("select");
n.id = elementName;
let opt1 = document.createElement("option");
opt1.value = true;
opt1.innerHTML = true;
let opt2 = document.createElement("option");
opt2.value = false;
opt2.innerHTML = false;
n.appendChild(opt1);
n.appendChild(opt2);
Form.appendChild(n);
let element = Form.querySelector(`#${elementName}`);
element.value = trueOrFalse;
```

Other ways I have used to try preselecting the value of the element n are :

```
if (trueOrFalse) opt1.selected = selected;
else opt2.selected = selected;
//and 
n.value = trueOrFalse;
```

Comment: Please may you update the code example to be a snippet that actually can be run without errors? See info on [mcve]s.

Comment: Option values should be strings, not booleans.

Comment: I've turned the booleans into strings and it's still not working